# how to display monthly statistics in php with mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have here a table and i am required to display the monthly statistics every type of injury.
incident table:

```
|incident_id| date     |narration|injury_id|
--------------------------------------------
|1          |2015-10-10|long text|1        |
|2          |2015-09-19|long text|2        |
|3          |2015-05-18|long text|3        |
--------------------------------------------
etc..
```

And i have here a view.

```
|incident_id| date     |narration|injury_id|
--------------------------------------------
|1          |2015-10-10|long text|1        |
|2          |2015-09-19|long text|2        |
|3          |2015-05-18|long text|3        |
--------------------------------------------
etc..
```

injury table:

```
|injury_id  |Month|Year|              
------------------------
|1          |1    |2015| 
|2          |2    |2015|
|3          |2    |2016|
------------------------
```

The primary key in the incident table is incident_id and the foreign key is the injury_id. The injury table is where the incident table is referring to. So i want to display this output in a table in html:

```
|Month             |Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun| Up to Dec
--------------------------------------------
|Homicide          |100|200|300|400|500|768|        
|Self Accident     |354|300|320|380|800|200|
|Vehicular Accident| 20| 40| 50| 90| 16|100|
--------------------------------------------
```

Since i have no idea what to do. So i tried this query.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_stats(d int, y text)
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=1
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS c FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=2
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=3
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=4
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=5
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=6
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=7
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=8
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=9
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=10
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=11
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM incident_view
WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y AND MONTH=12;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Just assume the SQL have no errors. So basically i have to call the stored procedures 4 times passing the id of each injury row to the stored procedure. 
My question is, is there a better way of achieving this output.

Comment: `SELECT month , COUNT(*) FROM incident_view WHERE injury_id=d AND year=y GROUP BY month;` The rest of this problem is for php and your framework. The view is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by irrelevant. Kindly enlighten me because it feels like my sql just too long. I used a view so that i could just query this way, erwhere year='2016 rather than where YEAR(date)='2016'.

Comment: There's no advantage in selecting from the view as opposed to the core table in this intance. I think views are only useful where you want to control access to data - but maybe others have a different 'view'.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that i am actually doing the sql twice?

Comment: I'm not sufficently well-versed in the mechanics of views to answer that - but I can see why that might be the case. Either way, use my query - but on the core table, not the view. (I suspect that you really want a slightly different query. I'll add it as an answer...)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') yearmonth
     , injury_id
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM incident
[WHERE date BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd'] -- optional
 GROUP  
    BY injury_id
     , yearmonth;
```

Comment: is the yearmonth an alias or something?

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio Yes.